# Why didn't Nagato give Naruto his Rinnegan?

Tags: naruto

Since Nagato was aware that he was going to die soon why didn't he give Naruto his [Rinnegan](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Rinnegan)? His was fully aware of his death and this is shown in episode 172-175 and also on [Narutopedia](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Nagato). The Rinnegan isn't a curse but more of great power, Nagato could've easily had his eyes implanted into Naruto and Naruto would've been almost twice as powerful as Nagato and the Six Pains combined. Was there something that was blocking him from doing so such as a curse mark or something such as that?

This has been bugging me for a while, but to reason with my question I would like to explain how he could've implanted them, There are only two canon ways to attain the Rinnegan. (Apart from [Ōtsutsuki](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/%C5%8Ctsutsuki_Clan)) These ways are by getting it from someone else or by By Merging Indra’s chakra with Ashura’s. The obvious way he could've gotten it was by getting the Rinnegan from Nagato or stealing it from his corpse. Naruto is not greedy enough to steal it from his corpse but Nagato was definitely able to give him his Rinnigan, but this was the only way of him being able to because of his [heratige](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Nagato), Nagato was a part of the Uzumaki clan but not the Ōtsutsuki clan so, therefore, he couldn't just implant them by touch or some sort of Jitsu. He has every reason to give his visual prowess to Naruto.

> F.Y.I. Nagato was not mad or angry with Naruto in his final moments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you think about it,

1. Would Naruto accept the Rinnegan, i doubt it...
2. Who would train him to use the Rinnegan... (Jiraya's Out Of The Picture :c)
3. Would the Nine-Tails React So Kindly To Naruto Getting Former Madara's Rinnegan... He's already angry to losing to Naruto, with his hatred with Madara on top i think that would make him think that Naruto is going to become the next Madara... Yeah that won't end well. It also messes up the story as Naruto probably won't be able to build a friendship with the 9 tails later...
4. Who would revive basically everyone in the Leaf... With Naruto having no clue how to... This messes up the story.
5. (This is a might 50/50) Saskue wouldn't be too happy with Naruto basically getting a much, much, more advanced Sharingan and he would probably focus his time getting a Rinnegan himself... Which messes up the story...